# Not able to make Ajax call using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I am trying to call a Sample API from my JSP using jQuery Ajax, but I am not getting success. I dont know where am I wrong but even simple html page is not getting loaded.

Here is my code.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello
        <div id="temp">
            <a href="#" onclick="callGetApplicationDetails();" >Click Here</a>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function callGetApplicationDetails() {
                jQuery.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data) {
                    alert('inside');
                    $.each(data.items, function(i,item) {
                        $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#temp");
                        if ( i == 3 ) return false;
                    });
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to load jQuery. Add the following to your `<head>`.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry for posting the same thing again..but can u tell me the problem with the following code.                                                $.ajax({
  url:"serverFile.jsp",
  type: "GET",
  dataType:'html',
  async: true,
  data:data,
  success: function(responseData) {
   if (responseData != null && callback != null) {
    
   alert('success');
   
   $('#dictionary').html(responseData);
   
    
   }
  },
  error: function(){
   
   alert('error');
   
   if (errorCallback !=null) errorCallback();
  }
 });

Comment: Press `Ask Question` button on right top and provide an SSCCE :)

Comment: sure Baluc, With the same statement i am posting it again :)